A different usage of "shouldn't have done"? | ".... I was smashed to pieces. I shouldn't have survived. I have no idea why I did..."
On TV, an English speaker tells about an accident he had. At one point he said:
"...I was in a an airplane that crashed into the ground in 2010. I was smashed to pieces. I shouldn't have survived. I have no idea why I did..." ITV - interview with an MP (see: 9:33-9:40)
The use of "...shouldn't have survived..." seems completely different from the sense we are used to seeing/hearing.  Obviously he doesn't mean "It was wrong to have survived". Clearly he means "It wasn't expected that I might have survived."
If my understanding is correct, this seems to be a very special usage that no other modal can come nowhere near in creating this sense, doesn't it?

Modals are used like this to show the certainty, possibility or impossibility of something. In this instance he is talking about the impossibility of him surviving (as you surmised).  This is different from the other use of modals for ability/permission/requests/choice. "Shouldn't have done" is talking about a permission/choice, shouldn't have survived is talking about a certainty.

It's sense 4 "used in auxiliary function to express what is probable or expected". As Merriam-Webster says, it's more normally used when predicting someone's movements e.g. "He should be there by 10 pm". Although you'll often hear "That should/shouldn't have worked."

People also say '[By rights] I should (or ought) to be dead now' about situations where they had a narrow escape from death, or were in a situation where most people die, like a plane crash, bad car crash. being badly injured, etc.

It doesn't have to be a bad situation either - I shouldn't be here, but a seat on the plane came free at the last minute and I was able to fly here today.

@MichaelHarvey, "I shouldn't be here" is also a good example. If I had seen it as is, I would have thought, the speaker wants to go back because he doesn't want to be there or he is unhappy there. Now I understand, he means he came there not because he planned but because he had an unexpected opportunity and he took it. In this case, "I shouldn't be here" seems to have the same meaning as "I wasn't going to be here". Is my understanding right?

@Yunus context is pretty important. "I shouldn't be here" could apply equally to someone trespassing without permission, someone in jail for a crime they didn't commit, someone narrowly escaping death or somebody ending up with a free concert ticket because someone else couldn't go and gave it to them. I don't think it's quite the same as "I wasn't going to be here" though

You're most certainly wrong with "no other modal can come [anywhere] near creating this sense". For example, The patient ought to have recovered , but died is essentially the same should / ought to... = was expected to...

@FumbleFingers, yes that is right. I just couldn't think of "ought to". I can perhaps add "be supposed to", but I am not so sure. Do you think "be supposed to" also create the same meaning? For example "I wasn't supposed to have survived, but I did."

Idiomatically, to [not] be supposed to [do or experience something] nearly always implies some conscious agent doing the supposing (by way of expectation or command). By rights you shouldn't / oughtn't to have survived falling out of an airplane, regardless of whether you did so by accident or because of your own or someone else's deliberate act (people occasionally do survive, though!). But if you weren't supposed to survive, that pretty much entails that you didn't fall out by accident.

Expanding on Stuart F.'s comment: Consider the positive version of this usage of "should."

I'm going to add this chemical to the test tube; the solution should turn blue.

This isn't modality; I'm not saying that I'm trying to impose my will on the solution or that it's obligated by a moral code. I'm just saying what is likely, probable, and expected to happen. If it doesn't...

That's odd, the solution turned green. That shouldn't have happened.

The solution hasn't been naughty, just unexpected.
This is the primary and best way of understanding the quote. But since it talks about humans and accidents, there could also be just a hint of "metaphysical modality" in it, or in statements like it. We often think of major accidents or narrow escapes in ways that relate to "fate" or some kind of supernatural will, structures of belief that have been part of the human experience throughout. People might say things like "I wasn't meant to survive." They talk about narrow escapes as "tempting fate" or "cheating fate." We don't have to find this idea present in "I shouldn't have survived," but it could be compatible with it.
